# Get date only in a DateTime in LINQ (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime, model-view-controller

When it's being displayed in the the View's datagrid, the dates are shown like `10/20/2016 12:00:00 AM`. Can I remove the time using the LINQ in my Controller? I tried converting it to string using different techniques but to no success.

Model

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string userdesc { get; set; }
    public DateTime startdt { get; set; }
    public DateTime enddt { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
var users = from u in _odb.USR_MSTR
            select new UserModel
            {
                userid = u.USR_ID,
                userdesc = u.USR_DESC,
                startdt = u.STRT_DT, //Can I get the date only from this dates?
                enddt = u.END_DT,
                status = (u.INACTV_DT == null ? "Active" : "Inactive")
            };
```

View

```
<tbody id="dbBody">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startdate)
            </td>
            <td class="hidden">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.enddate.ToShortDateString())
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: If you don't want to display the time then you need to change the code that displays it, not the code that gets it from the DB.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid That will just truncate the time portion to be midnight and the resulting `DateTime` will still have a time portion.  This is a display issue, not a retrieval issue.

Comment: @HarambeAttackHelicopter: I hope you're not storing strings instead of datetimes in your database, can you show the query?

Comment: That's because `UserModel.startdt` is a DateTime and not a string. Do formatting stuff in your view, not in your model.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's likely that the view is setup for `DateTime` and not `string` and the OP needs to do the formatting in the view instead of the controller or maybe use attributes as in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to suppress the displayed time you have to add `DisplayFormat` attributes to your Model

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string userdesc { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime startdt { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime enddt { get; set; }

    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

or format the date in the view

```
@foreach (UserModel item in Model)
{
     @string.Format("{0:d}", item.startdt) 
}
```